# Actions Sdk get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, ibm-watson

I'm trying to connect IBM Watson and Google Assistant, but I keep receiving this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined" and this "Function execution took 3323 ms, finished with status: 'crash'"

This is my code:

```js
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = actionssdk({debug: true});

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Olá, como posso lhe ajudar?');
});


app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
    var AssistantV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v1');
    var assistant = new AssistantV1({
        username: '###################################',
        password: '###################################',
        url: '###################################',
        version: '2018-07-10'
    });
    conv.ask("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        assistant.message(
        {
          workspace_id: '###################################',
            input: { text: input },
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        },
        function(err, response) {
            conv.ask(response.output.text[0]);
            resolve();
        }
        );
     })
});
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Log `err` before the `response.output` to check for any error

Comment: I receive no message in the screen, only a warning in firebase "Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions"

Comment: I need a payed plan to make others connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebeca, just to adding information, you are trying to add some outbound access, but you need to configure your account to do that.

> "Billing account not configured. *External network is not accessible*
>   and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove
>   these restrictions"

If you wanted to call some API (IBM Watson, as verified) you'd need to enable billing.

For the other quotas, [take a look here to see prices](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) - as you can see there are limits to the number of invocations using free tier.

Comment: Do you know any free alternative that I might use instead?

Comment: Yes @RebecaRose, you can use the **free tier**, and don't have any cost. But there are limits to use, but this limit you can definitely do a lot of tests.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sayuri

Answer (score 0):

Your `response`object is null. Check it is not equal to null before to use it:

```
let speech;
if (response !== null) {
    speech = response.output.text[0];
}
else{
    speech = "I'm sorry, there was an error and I'm unable to answer";
}
conv.ask(speech);
```